# Why does this particular INSERT statement fail?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to insert data from my ASP.NET web application into a SQL Server database table (which I have previously created). The code I have doesn't seem to be working, the error message displays, and the actual data doesn't appear to get saved to the database.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHRIYA\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=…;Integrated Security=True");

var insert = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tblRegister(GenerateID,Name,Surname,ID_Number,Gender,Address,Postal_code,Phone_Number,Email,Password) values(@GenerateID,@Name,@Surname,@ID_Number,@Gender,@Address,@Postal_code,@Phone_Number,@Email,@Password", conn);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GenerteID",lstuserID.SelectedIndex);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtsurname.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_Number", txtid.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddlgender.SelectedItem);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtaddress.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postal_code", txtpostalcode.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone_Number", txttele.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtpassword);

try
{
    conn.Open();
    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "error", "alert('Error When Saving');", true);
}  
conn.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @ShriyaBramdeo: Have you considered the implications of storing passwords (`@Password`) as plain-text? Please take a minute to read this: [**"You're probably storing passwords incorrectly"**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/); and perhaps this: ["Let's talk about password storage"](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2012/06/08/lets-talk-about-password-storage/).

Answer (score 1):

1. One error is to use `txtpassword` (i.e. a UI control as a whole) as a value for a `SqlParameter`. Replace it with `txtpassword.Text` (i.e. the textual value entered into the UI control):

   ```
   insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtpassword.Text);
   ```
2. Your SQL command text is missing the closing parenthesis `)` for `VALUES (`:

   ```
   SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert Into 
   tblRegister(GenerateID,Name,Surname,ID_Number,Gender,Address,
   Postal_code,Phone_Number,Email,Password) 
   values(@GenerateID,@Name,@Surname,@ID_Number,@Gender,@Address,
   @Postal_code,@Phone_Number,@Email,@Password)", conn);
   //                                         ^
   ```

Comment: I have tried that and it still doesn't save to the SQL server. Could there be a problem with my SQL Server?

Comment: Any error You are getting

Comment: The error message that i set if the data was not able to save.

Comment: replace `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "error", "alert('Error When Saving');", true);` with `throw` and tell me that error

Comment: or remove try catch block to cross check what is error

Comment: I did what you told me but it still isn't working it is giving me a System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: can You tell me on which line error is generating in your code ??

Comment: On the line that says *Conn.Open()*

Comment: @ShriyaBramdeo oh....i got `Initial Catalog` should be name of database, you wrote `...`

Answer (score 1):

```
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_Number", txtid.Text);
```

That should be

```
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Number", txtid.Text);
```

Comment: Other mistakes have been pointed out by other people

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tblRegister(GenerateID,Name,Surname,ID_Number,Gender,Address,Postal_code,Phone_Number,Email,Password) values(@GenerateID,@Name,@Surname,@ID_Number,@Gender,@Address,@Postal_code,@Phone_Number,@Email,@Password", conn);
```

SQL syntax is wrong.

Missing `)` at the last parameter `@Password`.

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tblRegister(GenerateID,Name,Surname,ID_Number,Gender,Address,Postal_code,Phone_Number,Email,Password) values(@GenerateID,@Name,@Surname,@ID_Number,@Gender,@Address,@Postal_code,@Phone_Number,@Email,@Password)", conn);
```

Comment: I tried that it still seems to not insert the data into the SQL table